# call service from ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory service called depotSvc. I add it to scope in the controller. When I access it directly from the controller, no problems -- it logs "foo" to the console. When I call it from my ng-click function, it does not log "foo" to the console. Is there a trick to calling services from within ng-click functions?

html

```
 <button id="a" type="button" ng-click="getAreaData(depotCode, a)">
```

js

```
$scope.depotSvc = depotSvc;

$scope.getAreaData = function(depotCode, depotArea) {

    $state.go("depot", {depotCode : depotCode, depotArea : depotArea });

    depotSvc.getDepotVehiclesFlatArray(depotCode, depotArea).then(function(data){
                    console.log("foo")
                })
            };
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a trick to calling services from within ng-click functions?

No tricks, you can access everything you expose to the scope (or controller instance in case of `controllerAs` syntax). So if you need your service to be available in HTML in Angular expressions you need to assign it to some scope property. For example:

```
$scope.depotSvc = depotSvc;
```

Comment: It seems to be a problem with my service afterall. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note, that calling asynch methods from template might be not that useful (because you can't defined then callbacks). For example in your case, `ng-click="depotSvc.getDepotVehiclesFlatArray(depotCode, depotArea)` is not that helpful. Synchronous methods are fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my service. I had a jsonp request call test data that i had a dummy wrapper around -- always wrapped by angular_0({}). JSONp would fail, presumably b/c it expects a different wrapper, ie angular_1({})... I think. Thanks for your replies. I changed it to a get request and hosted my data locally for testing -- no problems now.